# What AWS service limit prevents a large fleet of instances from launching?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to launch a fleet of 700 r4.16xlarge instances via spot request.

I used `cfncluster` to launch an fleet with `initial_queue_size = 10`
and `max_queue_size = 700`. However this fleet scaled up and maxed out at 50 instances (and only $120/hr :P). There are many hundreds of tasks queued up in squeue, but something is preventing more instances from being launched.

After I realized this, I attempted to create another fleet of the same instance type in the same region and received the following error message:

```
- AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup ComputeFleet Received 0 SUCCESS signal(s) out of 10.  Unable to satisfy 100% MinSuccessfulInstancesPercent requirement
```

I do not know what service limit I am maxing out as my limit for on-demand r4.16xlarge is at 20. Is there a limit for spot request instances separately from the on-demand instances?

I checked ec2 limits as well as the trusted advisor service limits (linked below) and nothing seems to be maxed out.

https://console.aws.amazon.com/trustedadvisor/home?#/category/service-limits

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: May be this helps: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-spot-limits.html

Comment: @PubuduJayawardana That's exactly what I needed. We have over 400 instances running. Thanks a bunch!